# Add new element to inner dictionary in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm using Python 3.6.4. I'm trying to create a nested dictionary shared by multiple processes, and add key-value pairs to the inner dictionary depending on the results of various functions.

Below is an example of my code.

```
manager = Manager()
scores = manager.dict()

def add_scores(name, game):
    global scores
    if name not in scores:
        scores[name] = {}
    if game in scores[name]:
        scores[name][game] += 1
    else:
        scores[name] = {game: 1}
```

An example of what the populated dictionary would look like is

```
scores = { 'John': {'golf': '1', 'football': '2'}, 
           'Alice': {'basketball': '1', 'football': '3', 'tennis': 2}}
```

There are functions for the various games, and depending on the outcome of those functions, a key-value pair would be created for each person.

I know the line `scores[name] = {game: 1}` is problematic because it just overwrites the `scores[name]` dictionary with the last game.

I've also tried the code below.

```
manager = Manager()
scores = manager.dict()

def add_scores(name, game):
    global scores
    if name not in scores:
        scores[name] = {}
    try:
        scores[name][game] += 1
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

In this case, `print(e)` gives me the `game` values. If I use `scores[name][game] = 1` instead just to test, there is no error, but the dictionary is empty, e.g. `{'John': {}, 'Alice': {}}`. I can't seem to add new keys to the dictionary simply by assigning a value to that key.

How can I add to the dictionary?

Comment: Could you use `defaultdict`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to remember that **`Manager.dict` will sync only during **setitem****. If you edit the value object directly, `Manager.dict` will not see the change and thus won't sync. (Because from `Manager.dict`'s point of view, the key is still pointing to the same value-object; `Manager.dict` does not monitor changes inside the pointed value-object.)

Here's a version that runs in Python 3.9 and Python 3.6 (and every Python version in-between):

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager


def add_scores(_scores, name, game):
    # First get the inner dict
    # No need to use .setdefault() because we're going to
    # overwrite the value later, anyways
    nmgm = _scores.get(name, {})
    # Modify it
    nmgm[game] = nmgm.get(game, 0) + 1
    # Write it back so Manager.dict will sync
    _scores[name] = nmgm


players = {
    "Alex": ["Soccer", "Soccer", "Tennis"], 
    "Bob": ["Tennis", "Quidditch", "Soccer", "Tennis"]
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    scores = manager.dict()

    for iplayer, games in players.items():
        for igame in games:
            p = Process(target=add_scores, args=(scores, iplayer, igame))
            p.start()
            p.join()

    print(scores)
```

Notice that I do not use `global`, rather I pass the instance of `Manager.dict` to the worker process. On my Python installations, initializing `manager` and `scores` outside of the `__main__` structure resulted in a `RuntimeError`.

Result:

```py
{'Alex': {'Soccer': 2, 'Tennis': 1}, 'Bob': {'Tennis': 2, 'Quidditch': 1, 'Soccer': 1}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Sorry I'm not able to accept this as solution since I've already tried the one provided by @Pranav Hosangadi. If I can accept 2 answers, I would.

Comment: @Rayne That's okay. Just want to share a gotcha w.r.t usage of `Manager.dict`, and hopefully you'll make great multiprocessing programs! :-)

Comment: I've just tried this solution and it works great for me too. In fact, I think I like it more because there's no need to do a deepcopy at the end. So I'll accept this as the answer instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your inner dicts need to be `manager.dict()` too, because they also need to be shared. This should work

```
def add_scores(name, game):
    global scores
    if name not in scores:
        scores[name] = manager.dict()

    scores[name][game] = scores[name].get(game, 0) + 1
```

I also used `.get(game, 0)` to get the value of `game` with a default of zero to get rid of the try-catch and if blocks.

Remember that once you're done, you'll need to unpack the inner nested dicts because they'll be `DictProxy` objects.

```
import copy
d = copy.deepcopy(data)
for key, val in d.items():
    d[key] = copy.deepcopy(val)
print(d)
```

---

Example (works with Intel's distribution of Python 3.6.3 on Mac):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import copy

manager = Manager()
scores = manager.dict()

def add_scores(name, game):
    global scores
    if name not in scores:
        scores[name] = manager.dict()

    scores[name][game] = scores[name].get(game, 0) + 1

players = {
    "Alex": ["Soccer", "Soccer", "Tennis"], 
    "Bob": ["Tennis", "Quidditch", "Soccer", "Tennis"]
    }

for iplayer, games in players.items():
    for igame in games:
        p = Process(target=add_scores, args=(iplayer, igame))
        p.start()
        p.join()


d = copy.deepcopy(scores)
for key, val in d.items():
    d[key] = copy.deepcopy(val)

print(d)
```

gives the output:

```
{
  'Alex': {'Soccer': 2, 'Tennis': 1}, 
  'Bob': {'Tennis': 2, 'Quidditch': 1, 'Soccer': 1}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Python 3.9: There's a `Manager()` call outside of `__main__` block.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work in Python 3.6 as well :D ... same RuntimeError raised.

Comment: Strange, I was able to run this in Python 3.6, and the output was what I expected. I shall accept this as the answer as this is the one I tried.

Comment: @pepoluan good point. I'm not sure what version I'm running (answered this from my home computer), but I will add that to my answer when I can.

Comment: @Rayne you should unaccept my answer and accept pepoluan's because it's a better answer and more generally applicable.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi well, if it works on your computer, I'll blame it on my Python installation, then. I probably activated some "strict" flags or somesuch, because I maintain some open-source libs and I need as strict behavior as possible. To reduce the number of issues user submit, y'know 

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yes, I've accepted pepoluan's answer as I like that it didn't have to do the deepcopy. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction and showing me an alternative way to do this!